# Overloading a function in a templated structure

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

For my homework, we have to make a templated structure with various variables and functions. Here is the shortened version of it:

```cpp
template <class Type>
struct vekt{
    Type *array;
    int len_of_array;
    int move(vekt<Type>* second, Type start){ ... }
}
```

How the function move works: it checks if it can move the first element of the array (array[0]) of the calling vekt into the vekt second, and if it can, it does so. You can move the first element of the calling  vekt if you can get that element as a sum of various elements from the second->array. Type start is a neutral element for addition of that Type.

So for example, for Type=int, if the calling vekt has this in the array: [4,5,6], and vekt second has this: [3,7,1], the function move will return 1 because the first element of the array [4,5,6] is 4 and you can get it by adding 3 and 1 from the array [3,7,1]. I made that function and it works.

This is my problem: I have to overload this function for Type=char, because different compilers see it as either unsigned or signed char. I understand what I have to do, but I don't understand *how* to do it. I don't know how to write the overload into the structure. Can I do this and then just write the code specific for char in the first function move? :

```cpp
template <class Type>
struct vekt{
    Type *array;
    int len_of_array;
    int move(vekt<char>* second, char start){ ... }
    int move(vekt<Type>* second, Type start){ ... }
}
```

If not, then what exactly should I do? My english is not the best but I hope that my explanations are understandable

Comment: What should happen if `Type` is already `char`?

Comment: You can't specialize the function, it's not templated. You have to specialize the struct, yes that includes either duplicating the rest of the code or making a common base class. Why does it matter if `char` is signed or not? Might be XY question.

Comment: @Quimby: Not true: you [can](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) specialize a (non-template) member of a class template.

Comment: @DavisHerring Are you sure? I don't see it in the link. How would specializing the function without the class even work?

Comment: @DavisHerring in case of signed char,  if the sum goes over 127 it will go into negative numbers. In case of unsigned, it will go into modulo 128. The idea is that if the sum of chars is over 127, then the function sees that as a case in which you can't get the first element of the calling vekt as a sum of elements of vekt second.

Comment: @Quimby: It’s the `A<int>::f` (and `h`) about 75% of the way down.

Comment: @idontknowmuchaboutalgebra what about overflows with other types? What should happen in those cases? Why don't you do the calculation in larger types then?

Comment: @idontknowmuchaboutalgebra: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.  But I didn’t ask what *would* happen naïvely, but what *should* happen (given that your code above would have two definitions for the same function).

Comment: @DavisHerring `template<> void A<int>::f(int);
// member specialization OK even if defined in-class
template<> void A<int>::h(int) {}` right? Honestly did not know one can do that. You can make that an answer I think

Comment: @Quimby: I was trying to tease out whether that was the desired answer, but I think you’re right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not *overload* the member function (providing multiple implementations for different argument types for the *same* `vekt` specialization) but (explicitly) **specialize** it, which can be seen as *overriding* its general definition for the case where `Type` is `char`.  The syntax is just

```
template<> void vekt<char>::move(vekt *second,char start) {…}
```

(Note that the template argument list can be omitted from subsequent mentions of `vekt` as well as all mentions in the class template.)